# WPF Binding in a binding Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to access a string property of a complex object that is the value of my Dictionary. The key is a property of my class.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=MyDictionary[{Binding MyClassProp}].MyObjValue}"/>
```

Binding within a binding is not working as it is not valid XAML. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the double `Binding` will not work. I haven't been able to test this but, maybe you could do something like this:

Have your class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void Notify(string propName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}
```

When your `MyClassProp` property changes:

```
private string _MyClassProp;
public string MyClassProp
{
    get { return _MyClassProp; }
    set
    {
        _MyClassProp = value;

        MyDictValue = MyDictionary[MyClassProp].MyObjValue;
        Notify("MyClassProp");
    }
}
```

Notice that when `MyClassProp` changes, you set another property with your dictionary's value. Then define that property to use as the binding:

```
private string _MyDictValue;
public string MyDictValue
{
    get { return _MyDictValue; }
    set
    {
        _MyDictValue = value;
        Notify("MyDictValue");
    }
}
```

And then change your xaml binding to:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MyDictValue}"/>
```